# How to run packages on the TFS through a master package in SSIS?

Tags: c#, sql, ssis, etl

I am building a master package to start the packages that match the required conditions. However, all the packages we have right now are on the TFS, it seems there is no way that I can call these package directly through execute package task in the master package. and we did not deploy those packages on any other places.

Can someone provide some suggestions of how to run the packages on the TFS (Assume the TFS permission obtained)? or any other way to call those package through the master package if not on TFS, or can we do some process at other places? Right now the variables related to the packages I got are package names (around 60 packages).

Thanks

Comment: Tried that, but the external Reference only for the local file that is not in the same package as the parent package. Or should I set some parameter/ expression in a specific ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can execute packages from TFS server.

> The Execute Package task can also run packages stored in the SQL Server msdb database and packages stored in the file system. The task uses an OLE DB connection manager to connect to SQL Server or a File connection manager to access the file system

**Reference**

- [Execute Package Task official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-package-task?view=sql-server-2017)